What's the value of teaching least squares in high school?
In the country I teach it seems common to teach high school students to draw a line of best fit by eye, but to not teach how to calculate the line of best fit.
After this students doing the applied math stream are taught to "use technology to find the line of best fit" and to interpret residuals and R^2. While the pure math (calculus) stream aren't taught anything about regression. Lo
Is there any value in teaching how to find the line of best fit without technology in 2024?

Might be my pure mathematician perspective, but I don't see how 'best fit by eye' is ever a useful concept and how it relates to the line of best fit by least squares. Pedagogically I could see starting out with 'best fit by eye' is not a well defined concept and is totally subjective and then use that as a starting point to define and explain linear regression but this doesn't appear to be what you describe?

I think it's fine to omit manual calculation of least squares.  The issue is not if there is "any" (epsilon greater than zero) value, but if the value is worth the time (since time is not unlimited an there are a lot of things to do).  You could just teach (i.e. tell, not prove) that the computer is minimizing the squared distances.
For reference, I (yeah, yeah sample of one) went to high school and college in the 80s and everything was best fit by eye in science and engineering classes (usually straight line, but occasionally with a French curve.  And then in work world, by the 90s when Excel (or Lotus 123 before it) were common, easy tools, it was using the computer to give a regression.
I think I remember having it explained to us that actually a line of best fit is a minimization of the squares of the distances ("least squares").  But we didn't have to do it manually.  (In contrast, I do remember being forced through a few tabular examples of calculating standard deviation.)  I seem to have done fine despite the omission. When I look at some book from the 50s by Deming or the like, I can relate to the discussion of manual calculations of least squares regressions...but I never did them.
I'm not saying there is anything wrong with teaching the kids and having them do some manual examples.  But I don't think it's some critical gap either.  Just give them some comment about what the computer is doing (minimizing squared distances), or maybe even a graphical picture on the board, so they have some clue what the computer is doing.


Is there any value in teaching how to find the line of best fit without technology in 2024?

Yes. Science teachers are there to teach science, not to teach how to use a particular piece of software to do a particular task. Having students use software to do this is a huge hassle and consumes a vast amount of time. If students are told to do it using software, they will typically want to do it on their own device, but that means that everyone will be using some different piece of software. Then you're walking around the room for an hour talking to students about how to deal with the quirks of a particular application, which you may not even know about yourself.

One can have all students do it on desmos, quite easily. (desmos app is free on phones.)

... and here is an online Geogebra example: https://www.geogebra.org/m/XUkhCJRj which allows the student to try to guess the line by revealing the squares and trying to minimize them. Using a pre-built web interaction should be accessible from any (most?) devices students have access too. Some of the interactivities I had a quick look at are poor.

Well, ideally, if one wants students to use software for least squares (or anything else), one should let them write the corresponding program in their favorite programming language from scratch and test it on a few examples. Computing the best fit line for large point sets by hand is outright boring. Telling them to plug the values into the program whose workings they don't thoroughly understand (and the only way to thoroughly understand the program is to write it yourself) turns them from intelligent human beings into mindless input/output peripheral devices.
